# URL key for specified store already exists. When importing

Tags: import

M 2.3.1

We are importing via Firebear.
When I import I am getting success.. the product imports but I get this error:

URL key for the specified store already exists.

Whenever I try and SAVE products...

We had previously deleted products from the table with 
"delete from catalog_product_entity;"

If I change the URL key in the feed.. the import works ok and I can save the product...

How can I "clean up" my database so I can import the original feed with the original URL key and have it allow me to save the product.. without "URL key for specified store already exists" error?

Comment: Roughly how many products?

Comment: Original feed was a few thousand.... Now after deleting them all  am just trying to import one product to test the import and its giving me the error

Comment: If this is on a dev store may be worth truncating url rewrite table and letting magento index process regenerate url keys and then see what happens. I believe there have been a few issues resolved in journey up to version you are currently using so there could be an underlying issue https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7298

Comment: Delete the WHOLE table? Won't that break other things? Yer is dev site.....

Comment: Try to truncate catalog_url_rewrite table.

Comment: Also, you need to check url_rewrite table for type "product". Remove those products data from this table too.

Answer (score 0):

Yep removing the product url rewrites fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue in more than 3-4 projects.

If you want to resolve this issue, you can upgrade your version with latest one or try below code logic:

Try this solution by overriding below function in your custom module :)

Path: vendor/magento/module-url-rewrite/Model/Storage

```
protected function doReplace(array $urls){ 
    $this->deleteOldUrls($urls); 
    $data = [];
    $storeId_requestPaths = [];
    foreach ($urls as $url) {
        $storeId = $url->getStoreId();
        $requestPath = $url->getRequestPath();
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM url_rewrite where store_id = $storeId and request_path = '$requestPath'";
        $exists = $this->connection->fetchOne($sql); 
        if ($exists) continue;
        $storeId_requestPaths[] = $storeId . '-' . $requestPath;
        $data[] = $url->toArray();
    }

    // Remove duplication data;
    $n = count($storeId_requestPaths);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $n - 1; $i++) {
        for ($j = $i + 1; $j < $n; $j++) {
            if ($storeId_requestPaths[$i] == $storeId_requestPaths[$j]) {
                unset($data[$j]);
            }
        }
    }
    try {
        $this->insertMultiple($data);
    } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\AlreadyExistsException $e) {
        /** @var \Magento\UrlRewrite\Service\V1\Data\UrlRewrite[] $urlConflicted */
        $urlConflicted = [];
        foreach ($urls as $url) {
            $urlFound = $this->doFindOneByData(
                [
                    UrlRewriteData::REQUEST_PATH => $url->getRequestPath(),
                    UrlRewriteData::STORE_ID => $url->getStoreId(),
                ]
            );
            if (isset($urlFound[UrlRewriteData::URL_REWRITE_ID])) {
                $urlConflicted[$urlFound[UrlRewriteData::URL_REWRITE_ID]] = $url->toArray();
            }
        }
        if ($urlConflicted) {
            throw new \Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\Exception\UrlAlreadyExistsException(
                __('URL key for specified store already exists.'),
                $e,
                $e->getCode(),
                $urlConflicted
            );
        } else {
            throw $e->getPrevious() ?: $e;
        }
    }

    return $urls;
}
```

Happy Coding :)

Thanks,

Ketan T.